# Weird Skyrim Build

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am considering making a fun Mage Build,but i can't decide which one.
Is it Viable to Play a sort of "Melee" Mage ? (I've seem some out there,but i can't confirm if its viable).

I would like something Wearing a robe(for mana regen),maybe with Sneaking,but i guess it would suck,right ?

My main idea is :
1: Sneak + Daggers for hitting
2: Some traps and precombat buffs
3: After the Dagger hit,change to destruction and kite
4: Maybe,some some summons to help in battles

This would lead me to points in : 
Conjuration for Summons,Alteration for extra armor (i wont use any), sneak for dagger bonus,one handed for extra dagger bonus,destruction for extra damage with spells,and eventually, enchantings.

This is impossible of being achieved because of the high number of trees to spread points + the high need of stealth to pick x15 dagger multipliers.

[Here is the build i´ve made](http://www.ign.com/builds/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim?d=00000000000000000010000000001111110010000000001212121110011100000000000011131000030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005000000000000000000000000000000000100000111)

Comment: The viability of a certain build is a grey area for a single player non-competitive game. You can do pretty much whatever you want. Its not like a certain build is so underpowered that you can't complete the main quest. Do whatever sounds fun to you! If you really want some opinions you may want to ask in chat instead (and that is the proper way to address @yx directly, rather than asking a question with his name in the title).

Comment: besides, there are people who have more answers in skyrim than me, you should go ask them :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it feasible to play a MagiSassin(tm) in Skyrim?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42179/is-it-feasible-to-play-a-magisassintm-in-skyrim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will refer you to this existing question

[Is it feasible to play a MagiSassin(tm) in Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42179/is-it-feasible-to-play-a-magisassintm-in-skyrim/42190#42190)

as it covers similar stuff (magic+daggers)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a speech only build. A "wise-guy" type who talks his/her way out of everything. Only fists, fine clothes, and followers for "bodyguards", as well as only leveling up speech. It would be a unique way to play the game and maybe give you a little bit of a challenge.